# How to get messages ordered by timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to get all messages by their creation date (which is timestamp).

My data structure looks like this:

```
messages
  XRJONcahNUgeNrfkH3cmITJt3409 (auto uid of owner - user)
    -KoOSxA2Iajk3kv20U_p (automatic uid generated by Firebase)
      message: "Hi"
      senderId: "X8Oxg5J9Imb12C1iYBXJT9P48909"
      senderName: "Dave"
      timestamp: 1505813320526 (automatic timestamp)
    -GdOSxR2Iajk3kv20U_p --- I NEED TO SORT THESE UIDS
      message: "Hello"
      senderId: "G7Oxg5J9Imb12C1iYBXJT9P48909"
      senderName: "Frank"
      timestamp: 1505813321024 (automatic timestamp)
```

And I get all messages like this:

```
database.child("messages").child(ownersId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if let messagesDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                for (_,message) in messagesDict {
                    self.messages.append((message["message"] as? String)!)
                    self.users.append((message["senderName"] as? String)!)
                    self.timestamps.append((message["timestamp"] as? IntMax)!)
                }
            }
            completionHandler(true)

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completionHandler(false)
        }
```

So the question is, how can I get all messages ordered from the oldest to the newest? I dont know how can I use ordering methods (queryOrderedByKey(), queryOrderedByValue() or queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp") in this specific case. Firebase sends me data in random order (I dont know if it is random, but it is not sorted by date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rashwan said, you'll need to call `queryOrderedByChild()` to get the items returns in the correct order. Then you loop over `snapshot.children` to ensure you also process them in the correct order.

So:

```
database.child("messages").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        print("\(child.key)")
    }

    completionHandler(true)
})
```

The important thing inside the callback is to not convert the entire snapshot into a dictionary, because the dictionary won't maintain the order of the items.

Comment: Thank you, but this dont work. FIRDataSnapshot is now only DataSnapshot (and println is print), but even if I change it, it gives me Type "DataSnapshot" has no subscript members on every child.

Comment: Sorry about that. I update the answer with some code I just ran in xcode. It prints `-KoOSxA2Iajk3kv20U_p     -GdOSxR2Iajk3kv20U_p` so the nodes are retrieved/iterated in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it is still not the answer. Please look at my updated question. EDIT: I tried that and it is not a correct answer. I have messages, under that is uid with reference to user, and after that are finally uids that I need to sort.

Comment: My code prints `KoOSxA2Iajk3kv20U_p -GdOSxR2Iajk3kv20U_p`. Isn't that the correct order? As far as I can see: `KoOSxA2Iajk3kv20U_p` is older than `GdOSxR2Iajk3kv20U_p`.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it works. I just have to add child(ownersId). But now I need to get data from DataSnapshot.

Comment: Both of you helped me a lot. I am gonna accept your answer, because I think you answered my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You use `database.queryOrdered` instead of `database.child` like this:

```
database.queryOrdered(byChild: "messages"). observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("\(snapshot.value)")
}
```

But you could also get the data as you have done today and then sort the list `self.timestamps` instead:

```
self.timestamps.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })
```

**Update:**
Create a model and append your properties to that model and then append to a list and sort that list after that. Like this:

```
struct Model {
    let message: String?
    let senderId: String?
    let senderName: String?
    let timestamp: IntMax

    init(message: String?, senderId: String?, senderName: String?, timestamp: IntMax?) {
        self.message = message
        self.senderId = senderId
        self.senderName = senderName
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

var models = [Model]()
models.sorted(by: { $0.0.timestamp > $0.1.timestamp })
```

**Update 2:**
To add the models checkout the code example below:

```
database.child("messages").child(ownersId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
    var models = [Model]()
    if let messagesDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
        for (_,message) in messagesDict {
            if let message = message["message"] as? String, let senderName = message["senderName"] as? String, let timestamp = message["timestamp"] as? IntMax, let senderId = message["senderId"] as? String {
                let model = Model(message: message, senderId: senderId, senderName: senderName, timestamp: timestamp)
                models.append(model)
            }
        }
        models.sorted(by: { $0.0.timestamp > $0.1.timestamp })
    }
    completionHandler(true)

}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    completionHandler(false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this do not work too. I think I described my problem wrong. I updated my question.

Comment: @Boomerange, check the updated post. I think that this is something that you need.

Comment: How can I append to model in that cycle?

Comment: Thank you, but this shows me Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' on message["senderName"]

Comment: Both of you helped me a lot. I am gonna accept Franks answer, because I think he answered my question. But I refactor my code because of you and learned something new. Thank you, Rashwan.